# A function to get the term parent

Tags: 7, database

```
function term_parent($tid) {
  $row = db_result(db_query("select * from {term_data} where tid = ?",array($tid)));
  if ($row['pid'] > 0) {
    $term = term_parent($row['pid']);
    $row['classid'] = $term['tid'] . '^' . $row['classid'];
    $row['classname'] = $term['name'] . '^' . $row['name'];
  }

  return $row;
}
```

I don't know why it is using `tid = ?`. When should I use `?`.
What's the meaning of `$row['pid']` and of the following line?

```
$row['classid'] = $term['tid'].'^'.$row['classid'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Drupal query, `?` should never be used. Drupal uses placeholders, which are listed in [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6), and that allow to

- type casting to a integer the value passed for the %d placeholder
- escape the string passed as value for the %s placeholder
- convert the value to a floating point value for the %f placeholder
- convert and escape the value passed for the %b placeholder

This means that, for example, `db_query("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE value = %f", "12")` would convert the string "12" in the floating point value 12.0, and `db_query("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE string = '%s'", "It's an example")` will change the string passed as argument to `"It\'s an example"`.

The query is wrong, in a way, as [taxonomy_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.install/function/taxonomy_schema/6) doesn't define pid (nor classid) as fields of the {term_data} table. The following part of the function will never be executed:

```
if ($row['pid'] > 0) {
  $term = term_parent($row['pid']);
  $row['classid'] = $term['tid'] . '^' . $row['classid'];
  $row['classname'] = $term['name'] . '^' . $row['name'];
}
```

The {term_hierarchy} table define a parent field, which is the ID of the parent taxonomy term, but the reported code is not making a join between the tables, and it could not find the ID of the parent taxonomy term, which then is not stored in the pid field.

Comment: the array $row is from the db_result, could i named the key  
optionally?

Comment: The array returned by `db_result()` or `db_fetch_array()` contains, as array keys, the fields defined in the database table and selected from the query string. As the {term_data} table doesn't define any pid field, the array will not contain any array index with that name.